# Bounce back animation difficulty with space invaders clone

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

```
import time
import pygame
import random


player = pygame.image.load('player.png')

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)




class enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 15])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        enemy_spd = 1


class Barrier(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([30, 10])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = player
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):

        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        self.rect.x = pos[0]


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([2, 10])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 2



pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode([700, 400])



all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
barrier_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

#Create the moving space enemies

###############
enemy1 = enemy(WHITE)
enemy2 = enemy(WHITE)
enemy3 = enemy(WHITE)
enemy4 = enemy(WHITE)
enemy5 = enemy(WHITE)
enemy6 = enemy(WHITE)
enemy7 = enemy(WHITE)
enemy8 = enemy(WHITE)
################
#create barriers
###################
barrier1 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier2 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier3 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier4 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier5 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier6 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier7 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier8 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier9 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier10 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier11 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier12 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier13 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier14 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier15 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier16 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier17 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier18 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier19 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier20 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier21 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier22 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier23 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier24 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier25 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier26 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier27 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier28 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier29 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier30 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier31 = Barrier(GREEN)
barrier32 = Barrier(GREEN)
###################

enemy1.rect.x =30
enemy1.rect.y =50
enemy2.rect.x =50
enemy2.rect.y =50
enemy3.rect.x =70
enemy3.rect.y =50
enemy4.rect.x =90
enemy4.rect.y =50
enemy5.rect.x =110
enemy5.rect.y =50
enemy6.rect.x =130
enemy6.rect.y =50
enemy7.rect.x =150
enemy7.rect.y =50
enemy8.rect.x =170
enemy8.rect.y =50
####################
barrier1.rect.x =0
barrier1.rect.y =320
barrier2.rect.x =30
barrier2.rect.y =320
barrier3.rect.x =60
barrier3.rect.y =320
barrier4.rect.x =150
barrier4.rect.y =320
barrier5.rect.x =180
barrier5.rect.y =320
barrier6.rect.x =210
barrier6.rect.y =320
barrier7.rect.x =300
barrier7.rect.y =320
barrier8.rect.x =330
barrier8.rect.y =320
barrier9.rect.x =350
barrier9.rect.y =320
barrier10.rect.x =440
barrier10.rect.y =320
barrier12.rect.x =470
barrier12.rect.y =320
barrier13.rect.x =500
barrier13.rect.y =320
barrier14.rect.x =590
barrier14.rect.y =320
barrier15.rect.x =620
barrier15.rect.y =320
barrier16.rect.x =650
barrier16.rect.y =320
barrier17.rect.x =0
barrier17.rect.y =330
barrier18.rect.x =30
barrier18.rect.y =330
barrier19.rect.x =60
barrier19.rect.y =330
barrier20.rect.x =150
barrier20.rect.y =330
barrier21.rect.x =180
barrier21.rect.y =330
barrier22.rect.x =210
barrier22.rect.y =330
barrier23.rect.x =300
barrier23.rect.y =330
barrier24.rect.x =330
barrier24.rect.y =330
barrier25.rect.x =350
barrier25.rect.y =330
barrier26.rect.x =440
barrier26.rect.y =330
barrier27.rect.x =470
barrier28.rect.y =330
barrier29.rect.x =500
barrier29.rect.y =330
barrier30.rect.x =590
barrier30.rect.y =330
barrier31.rect.x =620
barrier31.rect.y =330
barrier32.rect.x =650
barrier32.rect.y =330

enemy_list.add(enemy1, enemy2, enemy3, enemy4, enemy5, enemy6, enemy7, enemy8, barrier1, barrier2, barrier3, barrier4, barrier5, barrier6, barrier7, barrier8, barrier9, barrier10, barrier11, barrier12, barrier13, barrier14, barrier15, barrier16, barrier17, barrier18, barrier19, barrier20, barrier21, barrier22, barrier23, barrier24, barrier25, barrier26, barrier27, barrier28, barrier29, barrier30, barrier31, barrier32)
all_sprites_list.add(enemy1, enemy2, enemy3, enemy4, enemy5, enemy6, enemy7, enemy8, barrier1, barrier2, barrier3, barrier4, barrier5, barrier6, barrier7, barrier8, barrier9, barrier10, barrier11, barrier12, barrier13, barrier14, barrier15, barrier16, barrier17, barrier18, barrier19, barrier20, barrier21, barrier22, barrier23, barrier24, barrier25, barrier26, barrier27, barrier28, barrier29, barrier30, barrier31, barrier32)




player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)


done = False


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0
player.rect.y = 370

# Main Program 
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Fire a bullet if the user clicks the mouse button
            bullet = Bullet()
            # Set the bullet so it is where the player is
            bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x + 14
            bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y + 8
            # Add the bullet to the lists
            all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)




  ################STACKOVERFLOW#################
    if enemy1.rect.x<=700:
        enemy1.rect.x += 1
        if enemy1.rect.x>=560 and enemy1.rect.y<=55:
            enemy1.rect.y += 5
            enemy1.rect.x -= 2

    if enemy2.rect.x<=700:
        enemy2.rect.x += 1
        if enemy2.rect.x>=580 and enemy2.rect.y<=55:
            enemy2.rect.y += 5
    if enemy3.rect.x<=700:
        enemy3.rect.x += 1
        if enemy3.rect.x>=600 and enemy3.rect.y<=55:
            enemy3.rect.y += 5
    if enemy4.rect.x<=700:
        enemy4.rect.x += 1
        if enemy4.rect.x>= 620 and enemy4.rect.y<=55:
            enemy4.rect.y += 5
    if enemy5.rect.x<=700:
        enemy5.rect.x += 1
        if enemy5.rect.x>=640 and enemy5.rect.y<=55:
            enemy5.rect.y += 5
    if enemy6.rect.x<=700:
        enemy6.rect.x += 1
        if enemy6.rect.x>=660 and enemy6.rect.y<=55:
            enemy6.rect.y += 5
    if enemy7.rect.x<=700:
        enemy7.rect.x += 1
        if enemy7.rect.x>=680 and enemy7.rect.y<=55:
            enemy7.rect.y += 5
    if enemy8.rect.x<= 700:
        enemy8.rect.x += 1
        if enemy8.rect.x>=700 and enemy8.rect.y<=55:
            enemy8.rect.y += 5




    all_sprites_list.update()

    for bullet in bullet_list:
        enemy_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, enemy_list, True)


        for enemy in enemy_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)


#Make bullet disappear after going off screen
        if bullet.rect.y < -10:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Speece Invoders")
    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Draw all the spites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()


    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```

At the part where it says #####STACKOVERFLOW##### is where I have the problem, I am trying to make the first enemy move left after shifting down as in space invaders (the game is a clone). Yet all that happens is the enemy shifts down and comes to a complete standstill. Any idea on how to fix it? I am a beginner programmer and anything would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that without including all the variables needed

Comment: Look into the `list` type, and use some loops.

Comment: Can I do that whilst maintaining all the variables I have already called?

Comment: Also I'm really not sure how I would do that...

Comment: The point is that you have lots of variables, but only a few kinds of variables, so the expected route is that you put the similar ones into a `list`. Regardless, I'm guessing that the problem occurs even with only one enemy, which means you would be able to remove the code for all but one enemy (that's just one example of things you might be able to remove). The idea is for your code snippet to be as small as possible while still adequately representing the problem.

Comment: Here's some [information](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) about the `list` type.

Comment: Do you think you could give me an example? Im horrible with loops.

Comment: Here's some [information](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) about the `for` statement.

Comment: Maybe check out this tutorial: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: You don't seem to be keeping track of the current direction the aliens are moving anywhere. You can't just recalculate that from first principles based on their current position; you have to know whether they were moving left or right in the previous frame.

Comment: @abarnert Yes I figured that I'm just not sure how to fix it at this point

Comment: @Dominico909: Normally you do that by storing "dx" and "dy" attributes on each sprite or sprite group. Then you can do things like `s.rect.x += s.dx`. And then, when you set `s.dx = -s.dx`, that means next frame he'll go the opposite direction. I'm sure there are examples for this in the PyGame tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to make the track for the `Enemy` class would be to have a default track like this:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  path = [(0,0), (1,5), (2,11) .... ]
  def __init__(self, color, x, y): #adding additional x, y arguments will declutter your code
    super().__init__()
    self.x, self.y = x, y #assign coordinates NOW
    self.start_x, self.start_y = x, y #added to using path
    self.current_path_index = 0
    #et cetera

  def update(self):
    self.x = self.start_x + path[self.current_path_index][0]
    self.y = self.start_y + path[self.current_path_index][0]
    self.current_path_index += 1
```

The path created can be accessed as `Enemy.path` or, in an instance of `Enemy`, as `self.path`, sort of like `self.update()`.

What this does is make a default path for your enemies to follow, and have it increment each time the `update()` function is called for the sprite.

Comment: Alright Ill see if I can figure out how to implement this!

Comment: Now that I think about it some more, it may be a better idea to make a counter for each instance of `Enemy`, and have a similar list which updates rates of change for the position. You would have to have increments and so on.